# A story in the Bible where Jesus tested the faith of a sinner?

Tags: bible, new-testament, forgiveness, verse-identification

I'm looking for a story in the Bible where Jesus put a sinner's faith to the test.

I originally heard this story during a Church sermon.  It was nearly 4 years ago, and and I'm having trouble figuring out which book this verse could belong in.

I'm not sure, but it begins with a person asking Jesus for his forgiveness...  I think She was a Gentile.  Jesus Christ rejected that.
The lady claimed that she still believes that Jesus will still forgive Her mistakes, because of Jesus' love for the sinners.  In the end, Jesus revealed that He was just testing Her.  He then said that **because of her faith, she was forgiven**.

I kept looking for that story in many places, yet it still yields similar results.  Have you ever heard this story or something similar?  Do you think this story exist?

Answer (score 8):

This question does not really fit the criteria for here, but here are a couple of suggestions anyway.  First, your recollections of that 4-year-old sermon may be partially incorrect, plus the speaker may have added a few points that may not actually be in the Bible. Therefore, I have two possibilities to offer.

First, Mark 5:24-34. However, this lady was Jewish, nor did she ask for forgiveness. She expected healing, surreptitiously touching the hem of Jesus' garment in a pressing throng. She was instantly healed, but Jesus stopped to find out who had carried out that act of faith, causing her to come forward to admit it, and she was terrified. But Jesus was really kind to her, saying, "Daughter, your faith has healed you. Go in peace and be freed from your suffering."

Second idea, Matthew 15:21-28 - the most likely one. This was a Syro-Phoenecian woman (a Gentile) and the location was the region of Tyre and Sidon. She cried out to Jesus, "Lord, Son of David, have mercy on e! My daughter is suffering terribly from demon-possession." At first, Jesus ignored her and the disciples urged him to send her away, as she kept crying this out. Jesus then said that he was sent to the lost sheep of Israel. She knelt at his feet, again asking for help. He tested her by then saying, "It is not right to take the children's bread [Israelites] and toss it to the dogs [Gentiles]." She agreed but added (in faith) that even the dogs [like herself] get to eat the crumbs fallen from the [Israelite] table.

At that, Jesus said she had great faith, so her request was granted. Her daughter was healed from that very hour.

I think the reason you could not find the actual account is that you wrongly thought she was asking for forgiveness, when in both these cases, the women had faith for healing. But the second account fits the bill of a Gentile woman.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! The second one was what I was looking for ( Matthew 15:21-28 ) The speaker though never really added points to the story, I really had just a very unclear recap and memory of the story.. But once again Thanks!

Comment: @Hethaly9 Glad we could help you find it.  You can Accept the answer by clicking on the Check sign turning it green.